# Tengo problemas para obtener el string de una placa de un auto

Tags: java

En un proyecto de bluej no logro obtener el String de la placa(dato de entrada) de la clase carro en un método llamado existePlacaIniciaCon( char letra ) de la clase parqueadero.

```
 public class parqueadero{
private Carro c;
public static final int numeroPuestos = 87;
private double[] puestos;
private int tarifa;
public int libres;
…….
public boolean existePlacaIniciaCon( char letra ) 
{
   comienza = false
   String f = c.getPlaca();
    char k = f.charAt(0);
    for(int i=0; i< numeroPuestos || !comienza; i++)
    {
        if(k == letra)
        {
            comienza = true;
        }
        else
        {
            comienza = false;
        }
    }
    return comienza;
   //se vuelve true si existe alguna placa con la letra inicial que es el parámetro del método.
   //Ahora el problema que tengo es que al llamar al método no me devuelve false o true....
} 
….. la otra clase....
 public class Carro
 /** Placa del carro */
private String placa;
/** Hora de llegada del carro al parqueadero: valor entre 6 y 20 */
private int horaLlegada;

 * Crea un carro con la información básica
 * @param nPlaca - Placa del carro - placa != null
 * @param nHora - Hora de ingreso
 */
public Carro( String placa, int hora ) {
    this.placa = placa;
    horaLlegada = hora;
}

/**
 * Retorna la placa del carro
 * @return placa
 */
public String getPlaca() 
{
    String t = placa;
    return placa;
}
```

Quiero obtener la placa del carro, pero no logro.

Comment: Bienvenido @PROLEPRO a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Dentro de la clase "parqueadero" deberías tener almacenados de alguna forma los carros, de donde se puedan comparar las placas.

Comment: ¿Cual es exactamente tu problema? Un no lo logro no explica donde te atascas. Con hacer un carro.getPlaca() te deberia valer.

Comment: en el método existePlacaIniciaCon( char letra ) , obtengo la placa( String f = c.getPlaca();  )  , luego char k = f.charAt(0); para obtener la primera letra, y luego como se ve en el método hago un recorrido parcial para saber si hay alguna placa que comience con esa letra, pero a la hora de hacer la prueba y llamar al método no me retorna nada y me dice que "Error: cannot find symbol - variable <la letra que pongo>"